# Have nginx virtual host root in user directory

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I am configuring a new virtual host for nginx on my local macos machine and I need to specify the root directory as an existing directory in `/Users/abcd`.

I tried:

```
root /Users/abcd/GitHub/rails/public;
```

But I keep getting:

```
*1 stat() "/Users/abcd/GitHub/rails/public/" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

How can I fix this? I would prefer something that doesn't involve manually changing permissions to directories, since it will be tedious and error-prone to always do this whenever I add a new virtual host.

Comment: Add the nginx user (www-data) to the group of the user?

Comment: How can I figure that www-data is the nginx user and how to add it to the group of the user (which user?)?

Comment: In the config the user directive or: ps aux | grep nginx

Comment: The master process is run by root, the worker by nobody. Which one should I add it where?

Comment: the worker would make sense ;)

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on all my questions? It's not constructive at all to repeat each of my questions in every reply...just submit a full answer and I'll accept it if it helps me.

Answer (score 1):

I know OP said he doesnt Prefer to change permissions, But it's the first thing you should do.

Now to answer OPs situataion:

Add following line to nginx.conf

```
user abcd;
```

Now restart nginx service.

Comment: @unNamed I didnt get it, please elaborate.

Comment: Access is only granted where the user "abcd" has access. Other directories like the defaults won't work anymore.

Comment: This doesn't work for me anyway: `getgrnam("abcd") failed in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:3`

Comment: abcd is the username, should be created beforehand.

Comment: It is my current user, but I'm under macos, so it might be that users are handled in a different way than nginx expects them.

Answer (score 1):

In nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
```

Then you add the www-data to the users groups:

```
adduser www-data abcd
```

If you have multible users which home directories you want to publish you just add the www-data user to the users group.

```
adduser www-data <usergroup>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the first command doesn't work: `getpwnam("www-data") failed in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:3`

Comment: Then the user www-data probably doesn't exist, you can create a new user for that purpose: useradd www-data

Comment: If I try to use my own it should be the same thing. But I'm under the impression that macos handles users in a different way than nginx expects...